# Mypy: type annotation for map with abstract classes as values

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm working on a framework with various storage backends. Those backends all implement an abstract base class. The backend classes are stored in a mapping from the backend name to the class implementing that backend.

We want to be able to perform type checking with [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/), and annotate as follows:

```
#!python
import abc
import typing


class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):  # The abstract base class
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_name(self):
        pass


class B(A):  # Some non-abstract backend
    def get_name(self):
        return f'B: {self.name}'


class C(A):  # Another non-abstract backend
    def get_name(self):
        return f'C: {self.name}'


backends: typing.Mapping[str, typing.Type[A]] = {
    'backend-b': B,
    'backend-c': C,
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    backend_cls = backends['backend-c']
    # The following line causes an error with mypy:
    instance = backend_cls('demo-name')
    print(f'Name is: {instance.get_name()}')
```

Running mypy-0.501 gives this error:

`typingtest.py:32: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class 'A' with abstract attribute 'get_name'`

**My question:** How can we annotate the mapping `backends` such that mypy understands it only contains non-abstract subclasses of `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Guido](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3048#issuecomment-288754256), this is something that'll be fixed in a future version of mypy, when [pull request #2853](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/2853) gets merged.